# I need help with a banner in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just wanted to make this banner in LaTeX.
[image: Banner]

But I am not so good to LaTeX yet. So I have tried my best. Here is what I have managed yet:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=512pt, paperheight=128pt}
\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{c54544}
\pagecolor{rot}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white] (0,0) circle (1);
\fill[white] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What still misses is:

- placing the circle
- place the sunbeams
- place the text
- (use a filter - I think it's the photoshop "smudge stick") %not so important. For me it's enough if anyone could help me make this banner - with or without filter :)

Kind regards and thank you very much in advance! That would help me a lot to get better using LaTeX and especially tikz!

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use `memoir` here. Use `standalone` instead.

Comment: You're going to be hard pressed to realize any true 'filter' with TeX-tech.

Comment: Why can't you just export a high-quality version using Photoshop or similar and just `\includegraphics`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already noted in the comments the filter is problematic and it would be probably more convenient to make such a banner into GIMP or your favourite software and import it as graphics.

However, this is one way to achieve the sun with sunbeams and text without the filter.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto Black}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shapes}


\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{c54544}
\pagecolor{rot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sunbeam/.style n args={3}{overlay,trapezium, trapezium angle=#1,fill=white,anchor=north,rotate=#2,inner ysep=8cm,inner xsep=#3,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=.2cm},textnode/.style={font=\LARGE,inner sep=0pt}]
\node(a)[rectangle,minimum width=512pt,minimum height=128pt,fill=rot]{};
\node(b)[overlay,circle,minimum size=80pt,fill=white,anchor=south west] at($(a.south west)+(-.2,-.2)$){};

\node[sunbeam={88}{75}{1.2}]    at(b.10){};
\node[sunbeam={88.8}{92}{1.5}]  at(b.20) (c){};
\node[sunbeam={89.2}{108}{1.5}] at(b.28){};
\node[sunbeam={88.5}{120}{2}]   at(b.48){};
\node[sunbeam={87.5}{140}{2}]   at(b.68){};
\node[sunbeam={86}{192}{3}]     at(b.95){};

\node[textnode,anchor=north,rotate=.9]at($(c.east)+(3.5,.05)$){ONLY GOD KNOWS WHY};
\node[textnode,anchor=south,rotate=2.5]at($(c.east)+(3.5,.2)$){OGKW};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explanation

I'm using nodes to draw this to make advantage of the anchors and other positioning tricks.

First we draw a rectangle node called `a` of the desired dimensions and color:

```
\node(a)[rectangle,minimum width=512pt,minimum height=128pt,fill=rot]{};
```

Then we draw a circle node called `b` positioned roughly at the south west corner of the rectangle. To fine-tune the positioning I'm using the `calc` library:

```
\node(b)[overlay,circle,minimum size=80pt,fill=white,anchor=south west] at($(a.south west)+(-.2,-.2)$){};
```

Now for the sunbeams, I used trapezoid nodes stretched so that they end up outside of the rectangle. To customize the "stretching" I used the angle, rotation and width of the trapezium. Since we need many sunbeams it is convenient to make a custom style for them, like this:

```
sunbeam/.style n args={3}{
  overlay,
  trapezium, 
  trapezium angle=#1,          %sets the angle of the trapezium      
  fill=white,
  anchor=north,
  rotate=#2,                   %sets the rotation    
  inner ysep=8cm,              %sets the length and will ensure that all sunbeams end out of the rectangle
  inner xsep=#3,               %sets width of the trapezium
  xshift=-.1cm,
  yshift=.2cm                  %the shifts will ensure that all sunbeams start inside the "sun" (circle)
}
```

In our `tikzpicture` we only need to set the three parameters for each sunbeam and then place the sunbeam on the circle with the help of `border anchors` (you may want to check them in the TikZ manual) like this:

```
\node[sunbeam={86}{192}{3}] at(b.95){};
```

Finally we need the text. You may want to search for the specific font used in the original image (I just set a random font). We place the common stuff in a style, like:

```
textnode/.style={font=\LARGE,inner sep=0pt}]
```

and then place the text relative to one of the sunbeams (named `c`) fine-tuning everything with some `calc`ulations, remembering that the sunbeam `c` is rotated, so east, north, etc. anchors are relative to the rotation.

### With scaled text

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto Black}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shapes,decorations.text,math}


\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{c54544}
\pagecolor{rot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    sunbeam/.style n args={3}{overlay,trapezium, trapezium angle=#1,fill=white,anchor=north,rotate=#2,inner ysep=8cm,inner xsep=#3,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=.2cm},
    textnode/.style={
    decoration={text effects along path,text={#1},text effects/.cd,character count=\i, character total=\n,characters={text along path, evaluate={\c=\i/\n*200;},text=black,scale=\i/\n+1}}
    }
]

\node(a)[rectangle,minimum width=512pt,minimum height=128pt,fill=rot]{};
\node(b)[overlay,circle,minimum size=80pt,fill=white,anchor=south west] at($(a.south west)+(-.2,-.2)$){};

\node[sunbeam={88}{75}{1.2}]    at(b.10){};
\node[sunbeam={88.8}{92}{1.5}]  at(b.20) (c){};
\node[sunbeam={89.2}{108}{1.5}] at(b.28){};
\node[sunbeam={88.5}{120}{2}]   at(b.48){};
\node[sunbeam={87.5}{140}{2}]   at(b.68){};
\node[sunbeam={86}{192}{3}]     at(b.95){};

\path [textnode={ONLY GOD KNOWS WHY},font=\large,rotate=.85,decorate]($(c.east)+(0,-.425)$)to +(7,0);
\node[font=\huge,anchor=south,rotate=3]at($(c.east)+(3.5,.15)$){OGKW};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks to you and other helping users I get better and better to LaTeX every day! Thansk :D

Comment: you're welcome. There was a typo in the code that would prevent compilation (the custom text node was called `text` instead of `textnode`). Please check it again :)

Comment: That text line begs for text decoration with scale effect ;)

Comment: @percusse I was yet to reach pag. 600 :o)

Answer (score 7):

It was developed [several decades ago (click)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6652152#6652152). Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-node,multido} 

\begin{document} 
\multido{\n=-2.2+0.2}{21}{% 
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-3)(4,3) 
\pnode(\n,0.5){O} 
\multido{\nx=0+10,\ny=5+10}{36}{\pswedge*[linecolor=red](O){8}{\nx}{\ny}} 
\pscircle*[linecolor=red](O){1.75} 
\rput(O){\color{white}\bfseries\LARGE PSTricks}
\rput(O){\pcline[linestyle=none](0,0)(8;5)\naput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0,npos=.6]{\color{red}\bfseries PSTricks is fun!}}
\end{pspicture}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Not a complete answer but just illustrating one (not especially efficient) way of getting a "smudge" effect on the text.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{ugq}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\smudgeText#1#2{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=.]
    \node [text=transparent!0, name=@] {#1};
    \clip (@.south west) rectangle (@.north east);
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{@}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{@}{north east}}%
    \pgfgetlastxy\smudgewidth\smudgeheight
    \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\smudgewidth,\smudgeheight)+1)}\let\n=\pgfmathresult
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
      \path [draw=transparent, line width=rnd, line cap=round] (rand*\smudgewidth/2,rand*\smudgeheight/2) -- ++(135+rand*10:\smudgeheight/2);
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [path fading=., fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(@.center)}, fill=#2]
     (@.south west) rectangle (@.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip [preaction={fill=red!80!green!80!blue}] (-6, -2) rectangle (6, 2);
  \fill [white] circle [radius=1];
  \foreach \i in {0,45,...,315}
    \fill [white] (0,0) -- (\i-5-rand*2.5:10) -- (\i+5+rand*2.5:8) -- cycle;
  \node [rotate=15] {\smudgeText{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries ONLY Ti\emph{k}Z KNOWS HOW}{black}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]