# Is `Tikz` usable under just `standalone` and not under, say, `report`?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This nice and brief [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201096/10169) shows how to get any font smudged procedurally using

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{ugq}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\smudgeText#1#2{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=.]
    \node [text=transparent!0, name=@] {#1};
    \clip (@.south west) rectangle (@.north east);
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{@}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{@}{north east}}%
    \pgfgetlastxy\smudgewidth\smudgeheight
    \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\smudgewidth,\smudgeheight)+1)}\let\n=\pgfmathresult
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
      \path [draw=transparent, line width=rnd, line cap=round] (rand*\smudgewidth/2,rand*\smudgeheight/2) -- ++(135+rand*10:\smudgeheight/2);
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [path fading=., fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(@.center)}, fill=#2]
     (@.south west) rectangle (@.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rotate=0] {\smudgeText{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries BE \emph{VERY} AFRAID}{black}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Does this mean that `Tikz` is usable under just `standalone` and not under, say, `report`?

For example, how would I extend the above to the result below?

[image: report with tikz]

Comment: `\documentclass{report}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\node{works};\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- Of course you can use `tikz` independently of the class, so just change it to `report`
- add `\usepackage{tikz}` (as it was imported before by the option `[tikz]`)
- use a `foreach` loop to create the same node multiple times

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{ugq}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\smudgeText#1#2{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=.]
    \node [text=transparent!0, name=@] {#1};
    \clip (@.south west) rectangle (@.north east);
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{@}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{@}{north east}}%
    \pgfgetlastxy\smudgewidth\smudgeheight
    \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\smudgewidth,\smudgeheight)+1)}\let\n=\pgfmathresult
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
      \path [draw=transparent, line width=rnd, line cap=round] (rand*\smudgewidth/2,rand*\smudgeheight/2) -- ++(135+rand*10:\smudgeheight/2);
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [path fading=., fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(@.center)}, fill=#2]
     (@.south west) rectangle (@.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., 3} {
      \node [scale=\i*.5] at (0, \i*15mm) {\smudgeText{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries Don't panic!}{black}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```